# Change color of specific button inside ForEach loop SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a code that generates a list of buttons. What I want is when a button is pressed that button changes color. The problem I have is that the code does not let me do workout.isActive.toggle() as "workout" is apparently a "let" constant. How can I overcome this issue? I am still new to swift so any help would be appreciated :).

```
struct Workout: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var isActive: Bool

}

    struct Workout_builder: View {

var workouts = [
    Workout(name: "Bench Press", isActive: false),
    Workout(name: "Shoulder Press", isActive: false),
    Workout(name: "Incline Press", isActive: false),
    Workout(name: "Lateral Raises", isActive: false),
    Workout(name: "Tricep Cable", isActive: false),]
        
var body: some View {

    
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(workouts)  { workout in
                Button(action: {
                    workout.isActive.toggle()
                })
                {
                    Text(workout.name)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .background(workout.isActive ? Color(.white) : Color(.blue))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using SwiftUI 3.0, you could use this:

```
struct Workout_builder: View {
    @State var workouts = [  // <--- here
        Workout(name: "Bench Press", isActive: false),
        Workout(name: "Shoulder Press", isActive: false),
        Workout(name: "Incline Press", isActive: false),
        Workout(name: "Lateral Raises", isActive: false),
        Workout(name: "Tricep Cable", isActive: false),]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach($workouts)  { $workout in   // <--- here
                    Button(action: {
                        workout.isActive.toggle()
                    })
                    {
                        Text(workout.name)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .background(workout.isActive ? Color(.white) : Color(.blue))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I false other like if I select "Incline Press" and then "Lateral Raises" first one button is still while. How can I change it?

Comment: if I understand your question correctly, you can add `for i in workouts.indices {workouts[i].isActive = false}` just before the `workout.isActive.toggle()` in the `Button` action. This will put all workouts to isActive false, except the one you clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use index for such things then you can use for SwiftUI 1.0 or 2.0 or 3.0, also you need State wrapper for array:

```
struct Workout: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var isActive: Bool
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var workouts = [Workout(name: "Bench Press", isActive: false),
                                   Workout(name: "Shoulder Press", isActive: false),
                                   Workout(name: "Incline Press", isActive: false),
                                   Workout(name: "Lateral Raises", isActive: false),
                                   Workout(name: "Tricep Cable", isActive: false)]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            List {
                
                ForEach(workouts.indices, id: \.self)  { index in
                    Button(action: { workouts[index].isActive.toggle() })
                    {
                        Text( workouts[index].name)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .background(workouts[index].isActive ? Color(.white) : Color(.blue))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm a novice in SwiftUI, but try the following.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Workout: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var isActive: Bool
}

var workouts = [
    Workout(name: "Bench Press", isActive: false),
    Workout(name: "Shoulder Press", isActive: false),
    Workout(name: "Incline Press", isActive: false),
    Workout(name: "Lateral Raises", isActive: false),
    Workout(name: "Tricep Cable", isActive: false),]

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(workouts)  { workout in
                    ForEach(workouts, id: \.name) { workout in
                        CollectionView(workOut: workout)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CollectionView: View {
    @State var workOut: Workout
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            workOut.isActive.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("\(workOut.name)")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .background(workOut.isActive ? Color(.white) : Color(.blue))
        })
    }
}
```